# OPERADORES LOGICOS EN SENTENCIAS PREPARADAS

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

Estoy en la tarea de migrar consultas normales con mysqli a consultas preparadas...
pero investigando no he podido encontrar de manera clara como hacer estas consultas preparadas con operadores lógicos, específicamente el operador OR. A continuación muestro la consulta:

```
$sql2="SELECT 
    TURNO, 
    ASUNTO, 
    FECHA, 
    INGRESO, 
    LLAMADO, 
    REMITIDO, 
    FINALIZADO, 
ESTADO from $tabla1_bd 
WHERE ((FECHA=? AND LLAMADO=? AND FINALIZADO=? AND ESTADO=? AND (ASUNTO=? OR ASUNTO=?) AND REMITIDO=?) OR (FECHA=? AND LLAMADO=? AND FINALIZADO=? AND ESTADO=? AND ASUNTO!=? AND REMITIDO=?)) ORDER BY ASUNTO ASC, INGRESO ASC";    //  ASUNTO='INFORMACION' OR ASUNTO='LIQUIDACION'   CONSULTA EN LA TABLA DE CIUDADANOS PARA IR MOSTRANDO LOS TURNOS Q VAN LLEGANDO

        $llamado="00:00:00";
        $finalizado="00:00:00";
        $estado="POSPUESTO";
        $asunto1="VALIDACION";
        $asunto2="INFORMACION";
        $asunto3="";
        $remitido="";
        $remitido2="INFORMACION";

        $result2=mysqli_prepare($conexion, $sql2);

        $ok2=mysqli_stmt_bind_param($result2, "ssssss", ($fecha_actual, $llamado, $finalizado, $estado, $asunto1 OR $asunto2, $remitido) OR ($fecha_actual, $llamado, $finalizado, $estado, $asunto3, $remitido2));

        $ok2=mysqli_stmt_execute($result2);

        $ok2=mysqli_stmt_bind_result($result2, $fecha, $llama, $fin, $state, $razon, $remite);

        while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($result2)){
                echo $fecha . " " . $llama . " " . $fin . " " . $state . " " . $razon . " " . $remite
            }
        mysqli_stmt_close($result2);
```

Sé que es bastante extensa la consulta SQL, soy algo novato en esto, pero funciona correctamente para lo que la requiero... pero al pasar las valiables por `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` me arroja error de sintaxis...

**En conclusion:**

¿Como puedo aplicar un operador OR en `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` para que me reconozca que el campo `ASUNTO` puede tener 2 valores y también reconozca el otro operador OR que se encuentra mas adelante?

Aunque si hay otra forma de hacerlo mas fácil que me puedan ofrecer, la tomeré en cuenta.

De antemano, GRACIAS.

Comment: Por qué el operador OR es tema a tratar para la consulta preparada? Te da algún problema?

Comment: Si, ps no se como es la sintaxis para darle los valores al campo que utiliza el operador OR

Answer (score 1):

Mostraré solamente cómo pasar el parámetro de la consulta preparada. Si te refieres a eso cuando hablas de *optimizar*, una consulta preparada optimiza el código cuando se trata de una consulta que vas a ejecutar varias veces **en un mismo contexto**.

Esto es debido a que cuando mandas una consulta al DBMS éste diseña siempre un plan de ejecución, algo así como *`¿qué ruta debo seguir para obtener de la menor manera estos datos que me piden en esta consulta?`*. Ese plan, que tiene su coste a nivel de tiempo y de recursos, se prepara una sola vez y luego se reutiliza cada vez que esa consulta se ejecute aunque sea con otros datos... el manejador ya sabe la ruta pues ya la preparó previamente.

En ese sentido, incluso cuando vayas a ejecutar una consulta varias veces, aunque por motivos de seguridad no amerite ser preparada, lo puedes hacer por motivos de optimización.

Cuando digo **en un mismo contexto** me refiero antes de cerrar el script que ejecuta ese código. O sea, no significa que si lo usaste hoy mañana la consulta preparada se quedará ahí esperándote. Cuando se sale del script, PHP cierra todos los recursos de base de datos que pudieron haber quedado abiertos: conexión (a menos que sea persistente), consultas preparadas, resultados, etc.

No obstante, el uso de consultas preparadas en este caso aporta algo igual o más importante que la optimización: **seguridad**.

Entiendo que la dificultad que presentas es porque ha de pasarse el mismo dato dos veces como parámetro, la forma de hacerlo sería esta:

```
<?php 
    $sql="
            SELECT 
                TURNO, 
                ASUNTO, 
                FECHA, 
                INGRESO, 
                LLAMADO, 
                REMITIDO, 
                FINALIZADO, 
                ESTADO 
            FROM $tabla1_bd 
            WHERE   (
                        (FECHA=? AND LLAMADO='00:00:00' AND FINALIZADO='00:00:00' AND ESTADO='' AND 
                            (ASUNTO='INFORMACION' OR ASUNTO='VALIDACION') AND REMITIDO=''
                        ) 
                        OR 
                        (FECHA=? AND LLAMADO='00:00:00' AND FINALIZADO='00:00:00' AND ESTADO='' AND ASUNTO!='' AND REMITIDO='INFORMACION')
                    ) 
            ORDER BY ASUNTO ASC, INGRESO ASC
          ";
    # Se establece un control de errores
    if ( $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexion, $sql) ) {

        # Se liga dos veces el parámetro con la misma variable que se repite
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $fecha_actual,$fecha_actual);
        #Había olvidado ejecutar la consulta
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        # Se meten los datos en el buffer para podr saber si hay filas
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

        #Se comprueba si no vino vacía
        $filas=mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
        if ( $filas > 0 ){
            $msgOut="";
            // MUESTRA LOS TURNOS DE LA BD EN LA TABLA
            while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt)){
                $msgOut.= $mostrar['TURNO'];
            }
        } else {
            $msgOut="No se encontraron registros";
        }
    } else {
        $msgOut="Error: ".  mysqli_error($stmt);  
    }
    # Se imprime lo que haya ocurrido
    echo $msgOut;
?>
```

Aquí se *optimizado* el código en sí, estableciendo un control de flujo coherente: habrá una salida por pantalla, ocurra lo que ocurra. Un código que es mudo en ciertos bloques o que falla silenciosamente, no se puede considerar optimizado.

#### Más recomendaciones

Todavía la variable `$tabla1_bd` es un elemento peligroso en tu consulta. En ciertos escenarios un usuario mal intencionado puede manipularla para colarte una inyección SQL. Teniendo en cuenta que los nombres de tablas / columnas no pueden ser pasados como parámetros de consultas preparadas (como se hace con los datos en sí), lo conveniente sería que crees una *lista blanca*  de tablas y que pases por ese filtro la variable `$tabla1_db`.

Todas las otras dudas que tienes son relativas, dependen de muchos otros detalles y sería imposible responder, porque serían respuestas basadas en meras opiniones.

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Gracias por responder @A. Cedano, pensé que para que las consultas fueran preparadas era necesario poner la interrogación "?" a cada valor de los campos de la consulta, por lo que veo se lo pusiste solo al campo de `FECHA`. Mi duda es, por ejemplo si quisiera usar la "?" en cada campo de la consulta, en el campo `ASUNTO` de la consulta que puede tener 2 valores que son **INFORMACION** o **VALIDACION** si asigno 2 variables para que cada una contenga los valores mencionados anteriormente, como seria la sintaxis?

Comment: Lo intenté de esta forma, poniendo un OR entre ambas variables, pero me arroja un error:

`$ok2=mysqli_stmt_bind_param($result2, "ssssss", ($fecha_actual, $llamado, $finalizado, $estado, $asunto1 OR $asunto2, $remitido) OR ($fecha_actual, $llamado, $finalizado, $estado, $asunto3, $remitido2));`

Comment: No @andresuarez_95, así no funciona `bind_param`. Muéstrame cómo quieres la consulta exactamente, poniendo las variables en vez de los marcadores y te diré cómo tienes que escribirlas, dándote una explicación breve sobre cómo funciona. Es muy fácil y muy lógico, aunque es normal  que la primera vez cueste comprenderlo.

Comment: He editado mi pregunta @A. Cedano, ahí ya muestro como es que he intentado hacer la consulta, aunque si existe otra forma mas fácil la puedo tomar como respuesta aceptada.

Comment: Mi pregunta es la siguiente @andresuarez_95: ¿todas esas variables que ahora incluyes con valores hardcoded vienen de alguna fuente externa? Uno de los principios de las consultas preparadas es blindar la consulta cambiando los valores externos por marcadores y pasando esos valores aparte en el `bind` ... en mi respuesta sólo puse dos marcadores porque asumía que los otros valores eran conocidos de antemano (pues venían escritos a mano en la consulta). Si conoces esos valores no tiene sentido enviarlos a preparar porque no suponen ningún riesgo. ¿Me explico?

Comment: Si, creo entender @A. Cedano, pues de hecho las variables que he incluido no son de fuentes externas, lo único que representan son valores que ya vienen escritos en la `$tabla1_bd`, lo que puedo deducir de lo que me acabas de decir es que ¿para estos casos no es necesario preparar las consultas ? y ¿Solo es necesario preparar las consultas en caso de tener un formulario donde el usuario ingresa datos, como puede ser un sistema de login ?

Comment: Es simple: **siempre** que haya un dato que provenga de una fuente externa (aunque sea un solo dato o aunque sean 100 datos, da igual), hay que preparar la consulta. ¿Por qué? Porque ese dato que viene de fuera es un activo que cualquier usuario mal intencionado puede manipular, modificar, para colarte cualquier tipo de inyección, no sólo a nivel de la base de datos, sino incluso a nivel del sistema (porque desde la base de datos se puede incluso leer/escribir en archivos del sistema). En tu consulta inicial hay un valor `$fecha_actual`, si viene de fuera debes preparar **ese dato**.

Comment: La variable `$fecha_actual` como su nombre indica, me da la fecha actualizada automáticamente de acuerdo al día, entonces no tendría que prepararla. Eso ya lo entiendo, como bien decías, las consultas preparadas solo se ejecutan una vez, por lo que mejoran el rendimiento, ahora mi pregunta seria, es posible hacer la consulta sin pasar ningún marcador pero que solo se ejecute una vez como si fuera preparada? simplemente tendría que descartar `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` ? esto con el objetivo de mejorar el rendimiento del sistema...

Comment: @andresuarez_95 OJO, no dije que la consulta preparada se ejecuta una sola vez, sino que **prepara el plan de ejecución una sola vez**. O sea, cualquier consulta que mandes al DBMS éste diseña un plan de ejecución, algo así como *qué ruta debo seguir para llegar más rápido a esos datos que me pide esta consulta*. En la consultas preparadas ese **plan** se diseña una sola vez y se usa cada vez que la consulta se ejecute. Por ejemplo si en un código piensas ejecutar la misma consulta varias veces con datos diferentes, puedes usar consultas preparadas incluso si no hay datos externos...

Comment: ... en ese caso lo harías no por motivos de seguridad, sino de **optimización**. Ahora bien, si la consulta se va a ejecutar solamente una vez y no hay datos externos en ella, lo mejor es usar `query`, porque preparar la consulta también tiene un coste y no vale la pena si no vas a re-utilizar ese plan de ejecución. OJO: cuando digo *re-utilizar* me refiero a **esa llamada** del script, no a llamar al script hoy y luego dentro de 3 días. Cuando un script se cierra sales del contexto, no es que prepares la consulta y se quede ahí preparada esperándote para cuando vuelvas en 3  días.

Comment: Si, en este caso el script lo estoy ejecutando cada segundo automáticamente, porq es una tabla que debe ir mostrando los datos en tiempo real, por eso lo actualizo cada segundo, entonces como podria hacer la consulta asi sin pasarle marcadores pero con el objetivo de optimizar...

Comment: @andresuarez_95 todo esto son muchas preguntas y todas sobre temas diferentes. Esto da para escribir un libro. Lo que ahora preguntas depende de muchos factores. Y si hablas de ejecuciones masivas (cada segundo) eso hay que verlo muy despacio. Y, lo que te digo no tiene que ver con el tiempo (solamente), sino con el contexto. Si tú sales del script aunque sea por un segundo, cuando lo llamas de nuevo, es como si lo cierras y lo vuelves a abrir dentro de un año, todos los recursos se cierran. Pero ese es otro tema, no es posible abordar todo eso aquí. Ahí podrían entrar cosas como persistencia

Comment: Bueno, creo q dejaré la consulta normal tal cual como la tenia por ahora, gracias por despejarme de varias dudas, ya entiendo mas acerca de las consultas preparadas.